# How do I properly require jquery and JSDOM in my code using node?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jsdom

I am having trouble requiring jquery and JSDOM. I am using node coded in atom with nightmarejs already installed and required and nightmarejs works properly.

For jquery and JSDOM I did the same thing as nightmarejs and used:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install JSDOM --save
```

I currently have in my coding:

```
var Nightmare = require ('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true , height: 900});
const  jsdom  =  require("jsdom");
const   { JSDOM }  = jsdom;
    require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        var $ = require("jquery")(window);
    });
```

If I delete all coding that involves JSDOM and jquery my coding will work but as soon as I require them and run it in the terminal I get the error:

```
require(...).env is not a function
```

So what do I need to do to get it to work properly?

Comment: Please stop adding the `atom-editor` tag, unless your question is directly about Atom. Your problem has nothing to do with the editor you're using and providing that info helps no one. https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find my answer on my own. You cannot use .env in the newest update so correctly require i used:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
global.document = document;

var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```